# My app was built with flutter, using version 2.5.3, /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so Crash

Tags: dart

My app was built with flutter, using version 2.5.3, and was listed on the Google Play Store. Through the crash log, I saw that MediaTek CPU machines (SM, OPPO, vivo) had serious crashes in graphics rendering. Crash, reason/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so, how can i solve
backtrace:
#00  pc 0x00000000000c9f1c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
#01  pc 0x000000000012fe34  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
#02  pc 0x000000000012e9b0  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so (glTexImage2D+320)
#03  pc 0x0000000000092524  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_meow.so (MEOW::meow_call_ddk_gl_2_glTexImage2D(unsigned int, int, int, int, int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*)+44)
#04  pc 0x00000000004f7be8  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#05  pc 0x00000000004f33a8  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#06  pc 0x000000000046ed9c  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#07  pc 0x000000000046f008  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#08  pc 0x000000000047b000  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#09  pc 0x000000000047562c  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#10  pc 0x0000000000482424  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#11  pc 0x0000000000475324  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#12  pc 0x00000000004c5418  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#13  pc 0x00000000004c559c  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#14  pc 0x00000000004c7410  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#15  pc 0x00000000003091c4  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#16  pc 0x00000000002fe048  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#17  pc 0x0000000000308ecc  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#18  pc 0x00000000002fd09c  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#19  pc 0x00000000002fff20  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#20  pc 0x000000000001a064  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+916)
#21  pc 0x0000000000019c68  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112)
#22  pc 0x0000000000012d3c  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+100)
#23  pc 0x0000000000300030  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#24  pc 0x00000000002fc950  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#25  pc 0x00000000002fe830  /data/app/~~rBkk-gYPcdlfdPe9V0spnA==/com.haha.vip-qB6d5M-SUiEZ1puvWcBIaw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
#26  pc 0x00000000000b0838  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
#27  pc 0x00000000000505d0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)

I hope you can help me solve this fatal problem as soon as possible, and help me contact the Flutter development team and ask them to retest this problem.